# Loading data in ViewModel that have been retrieved in SplashActvity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I'm new with the ViewModel and I understand that it's a powerful and easy way to communicate with fragments.

My problem is the following : How to load the data retrieved in the SplashActivity in the ViewModel of the mainActivity ?

My app achitecture is the following :

1. SplashActivity : retrieve data with retrofit and store it into a List
2. Main Activity : contains two fragments displaying the data in different ways

Here is a piece of code showing my implementation.

**SplashActivity**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "TAG.SplashActivity";
    public static List<Toilet> toiletList = new ArrayList<>(); // HERE IS THE DATA I WANT TO 
    RETRIEVE IN THE MAIN ACTIVITY

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
        GetDataService service = ...;
        // MY STUFF RETROFIT including
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("toiletList", (Serializable) toiletList);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private List<Toilet> toiletList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        Serializable s = intent.getSerializableExtra("toiletList");
        // Check type and cast
        if (s instanceof List<?>) {
            for (Object o : (List<?>) s) {
                if (o instanceof Toilet) {
                    toiletList.add((Toilet) o);
                }
            }
        }

        // SETTING UP FRAGMENTS
    }
}
```

**FragmentExample**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public static List<Toilet> toiletArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

       // SETTING UP UI
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ToiletListViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ToiletListViewModel.class);
        model.getToiletList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Toilet>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Toilet> toilets) {
                //  update UI
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ToiletListViewModel**

```
public class ToiletListViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private MutableLiveData<List<Toilet>> toiletList;

    public LiveData<List<Toilet>> getToiletList() {
        if (toiletList == null) {
            toiletList = new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadToilets();
        }
        return toiletList;
    }

    private void loadToilets() {
        // asynchronously fetch toilets
        // HERE IS MY PROBLEM : How to access the toiletList retrieved
        in the SplashActivity ?
        toiletList.setValue(SplashActivity.toiletList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCleared() called");
    }
}
```

I hope that's clear. If you want any further info, fell free to ask !

Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [share](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) your `ToiletListViewModel` between the `MainActivity` and its `Fragment`s.

So what you need is to provide your `ViewModel` with `MainActivity` scope (It means you bound the lifecycle of your `ViewModel` to your Activity) and call `initToilets` then child fragments can easily retrieve this `ViewModel` and observe on its `LiveData`.

**ToiletListViewModel:**

```
public class ToiletListViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<List<Toilet>> toiletList = new MutableLiveData();

    public LiveData<List<Toilet>> getToiletList() {
        return toiletList;
    }

    private void initToilets(List<Toilet> toilets) {
        toiletList.setValue(toilets);
    }


}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private List<Toilet> toiletList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        Serializable s = intent.getSerializableExtra("toiletList");
        // Check type and cast
        if (s instanceof List<?>) {
            for (Object o : (List<?>) s) {
                if (o instanceof Toilet) {
                    toiletList.add((Toilet) o);
                }
            }
        }
     ToiletListViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ToiletListViewModel.class);
     vm.initToilets(toiletList);
        // SETTING UP FRAGMENTS
    }
}
```

So, when `setValue` is called, Fragments that listen to the `toiletList` live data will be notified.

**Note:**

You can create a shared `ViewModel` without providing it on `MainActivity`, instead of calling

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ToiletListViewModel.class);
```

in your Fragment do

```
ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ToiletListViewModel.class);
```

Comment: I think that's what I need ! I'm gonna try this ! So the `initToilets` replace the `loadToilets` ?

Comment: I think that a problem can appears. Indeed, if initToilet is not called, the toiletList is `null` and `getToiletList` can return null. Should I instantiate the attribute like this : `private MutableLiveData<List<Toilet>> toiletList = new MutableLiveData<>();` ?

Comment: And finally, what's happening if I retrieve the toilets into the ViewModel asynchronously and that I'm not binding the ViewModel to the Activity in mainActivity ? Is this working or the binding in the main activity is mandatory ?

Comment: @Maxouille Yes try to create an empty `MutableLiveData`. Binding in `MainActiviry` is mandatory, by calling `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())`  in your Fragments you actually tell the ViewModelProviders that this ViewModel is part of my activity lifecycle

Comment: Thanks ! I'm gonna try this asap !

Comment: The `onChanged` method is not called in the fragment. I'm not updating anything right now but I would like to retrieve the toiletList when the fragment is created in order to update the UI consequently. How can I access the data from the viewModel  outside of the `onChanged` ?

Comment: @Maxouille you can use `livedata. getValue()` to check that it has value or not

Answer (score 0):

There are two suggestions:

You can add data to list directly **(Off Topic)**:

```
if (s instanceof List<?>) {
    for (Object o : (List<?>) s) {
        if (o instanceof Toilet) {
            toiletList.add((Toilet) o);
        }
    }
}
```

use this instead of:

```
if (s instanceof List<?>) {
    toiletList.addAll((List<Toilet>)s);
}
```

**Back to main topic:**

You can take `ViewModel` instance of Activity instead of this in `Fragment`. How?

Take `ViewModel` in activity as below,

```
ToiletListViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ToiletListViewModel.class);
```

& for `Fragment` share it like this,

```
ToiletListViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ToiletListViewModel.class);
```

This will share your `ViewModel` between fragments inside of activity & observe your `livedata`.

Comment: Are you sure that the cast will work ? If the objects inside the list aren't Toilet, will it raise an exception or whatever ?

Comment: You're passing list of `Toilet` from splash activity, right? If yes then you're also checking it in condition, just replace `?` wildcard type to your `Toilet ` class and it'll work

Comment: **More importantly** do you understand solution about `ViewModel`  I've provided? If no then I'll update my answer with some more code to help you understand how it can work for you

Comment: Thx ! 
I understand but the answer of @Saeed is more clear and it seems working

Answer (score 0):

In order to get use out of the a view model, you need to store a reference to it's instance in your activities and then interface with them to modify data.

I would first of all suggest to you that you read the [developer guide on View Model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

When you are set-up and storing a reference to the model in your activities and fragments, you could add a method to the model, like `setToilets(List<Toilet>)`, which updates the toilets in the View Model, calls `loadToilets()` or stores the raw toilets so `loadToilets()` can later access it and now what toilets to load.
Then you can access all the data that you want to expose from other classes by writing the respective methods, just like you did with the `getToiletList(LiveData<Toilet>)` -method.